# How can I make all locations point to the same port? (nginx)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, web-development-server

I made a website using express.js and nginx, but whenever I want to add new route, I need to add the location (and give it the same port) in the nginx default server config. Is there a way to point all locations to the one port?

code:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location /about {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location /projects {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location /projects/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location /javascripts/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

I tried using * and a bunch of other general conventions for "all", but none of them worked.

Comment: Adding your config will help others to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarioMateaș sorry it took so long I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `include` file that holds all your repetitive config